I have a problem with a For loop and A Dictionary in Godot 4 where it create an infinit loop
I wanted to add 1 to a variable for every element in a dictionary.
I tried something like this :
Fruits = {}
var NumberOfFruits = 0

Fruits["apple"] = {"color":"red"}
Fruits["banana"] = {"color":"yellow"}
Fruits["orange"] = {"color":"orange"}

for i in Fruits:
    NumberOfFruits += 1

So thats what I tried and I expected to get : NumberOfFruits = 3
But I got an infinite loop that was counting up FOREVER

Doesn't GDScript have a built-in function like Python's len()?

I don't know GDScript, but I find this hard to believe. If you print i during the loop, what do you see?

You should put var before the Fruits = {}, it should look like this:
    var Fruits = {}
    var NumberOfFruits = 0

    Fruits["apple"] = {"color":"red"}
    Fruits["banana"] = {"color":"yellow"}
    Fruits["orange"] = {"color":"orange"}

    for i in Fruits:
        NumberOfFruits += 1

Othrewise, this code works perfectly fine
